# Load Slideshow on different page from first/last image next/prev click within current slideshow

Tags: jquery-selectors

Have researched this but can't find solution for this particular action.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.Thank you

I am using a simple jquery slideshow  "slides".
I have 10 galleries on ten different pages with a Main Navigation to access each gallery seperately.

i.e. GALLERY 1    GALLERY 2   GALLERY 3 etc.

I would also like to link the galleries one after another accessible via Prev/next within the slide-show instead of returning to main nav to choose.

e.g.
Click on Gallery 6  cycle  through via Next/Prev -  on last image in Gallery on click load Gallery 7  first image ( do not loop back to beginning of current gallery)

OR

click on PREV load first image in Gallery 5.

I have tried a number of different ways including this. But am not jquery savvy as regards this. And must be missing something important

```
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script></head>
     <body><ol id="new-page"></ol>

     <script>
     $("#new-page").load("/atest4.html");</script>
```

and also tried just loading the Gallery within the page with above code  (like iframe) 
GALLERY 2, GALLERY 3,  etc.etc.

But can't get to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Please let us know which jQuery slideshow plugin you're using and if possible, post a code example to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)